# How to change getDate format?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}
```

Date format for this code is `Sun Mar 19 2017 16:17:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

How to change this format to `Sun Mar 19`
Also how to add suffix to date? (st, nd, rd, th)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below function,

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  locale = "en-us";
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  var curr_date = dat.getDate();
  var s=["th","st","nd","rd"];
  v= curr_date %100;
  var curr_month = dat.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "short" });
  return ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'][dat.getDay()] +" " + curr_month + " " + curr_date +(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. is it possible to add suffix to date? (st, nd, rd, th)